# : Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh-keys

i am trying to do gerrit review using ssh command line argument.i am getting error as : Permission denied (publickey).for .ssh folder.

i tried with below steps also still no luck.

```
.ssh directory: 700 (drwx------)
public key (.pub file): 644 (-rw-r--r--)
private key (id_rsa): 600 (-rw-------)
```

i have also regenerated ssh key and pasted it in git.

command works fine if it execute it on my pc.i am facing problem when i execute it on agent.

i also tried setting read write permission to .ssh folder

Comment: The `~/.ssh` directory must _always_ have `700` permissions, unless the SSH client has been configured to save specific SSH files in another directory.